# Compare Keys in Informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am trying to solve an Informatica problem

I have two tables: Table A and Table B have the following structure

**Table A**
A_Key
A_Name
A_Address

**Table B**
B_Key
B_Name
B_Address
A_Key (Foreign Key)

I need to make sure that **Every A_Key in Table B exist as A_Key in Table A**.

Since I am new to Informatica Data Quality tool, I am trying to find the logic how I can implement this.

One logic that I can think is creating **Rule**

Does anyone have a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a joiner between Table B (as master) and Table A (as detail), the joiner type must be detail outer, so you will get all rows in table B and their equivalent in table A. Then you could obtain those rows in table B wich doesn't have an equivalent in Table A using a filter transformation. And finally you can count the rows using an aggreation transformation.

Table A

```
       Joiner A-B   --- Filter (a is null) -- Agregator (count rows)
```

Table B